# Starting up LaTeX file on Mac for first time: "log file not found" error

Tags: errors, miktex, texmaker, macos

I have just installed texmaker on my Macbook Air M1, 2020 along with Miktex. It is macOS Ventura 13.1. After setting up a minimal file, it returns the error "Log File not found!" (this is the entire error message). This worked fine when I did it a while back on my Windows laptop. What can I do to remedy this problem?

This is the entire file:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
hi
\end{document}
```

Comment: Which version of MacOS is installed on your laptop? Please also edit your posting to show the entire error message.

Comment: @Mico It is macOS Ventura 13.1. The error message was very brief "Log File not found!" and the document does not load. Edited as per your suggestion.